# What is difference between crypto and bcrypt

Tags: node.js, cryptography, bcrypt

These modules are required like that

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
```

I'm very confused in between them. I want to know what is difference between them and when it should be used.

Comment: Removed the line asking for an example as that is explicitly off topic on this Q/A site.

Answer (score 8):

The bcrypt module contains an implementation of the bcrypt *password hashing algorithm* and nothing else.

The built-in crypto module contains many cryptographic primitives such as *hashing, symmetric and asymmetric encryption, key exchange and some more*. It doesn't contain an implementation of bcrypt, but there is an implementation of PBKDF2 which has a similar goal (password hashing) but not as good as bcrypt.

Comment: Hi, so if i am developing a banking app should i use bcrypt or crypto to encrypt the user information?

Comment: No idea. I haven't looked at the requirements of PCI DSS. You could use both. Whether you must is another question.

Comment: Should i use the builtin crypto module in node or crypto-js? Also, do you suggest i use scrypt or bcrypt?

Comment: 1. The crypto module probably uses optimized code in V8 whereas crypto-js is implemented purely in JS. If you don't care about performance then whatever you're more comfortable with. crypto-js only provides symmetric primitives whereas crypto provides asymmetric too. 2. scrypt with a high work factor which depends on the delay your users will tolerate.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. So, if i was to develop a banking app will bcrypt do the job in hashing the passwords or do you suggest i use the crypto module and encode using SHA?

Comment: Again, I don't know what the requirements for banking in your jurisdiction are.

Comment: I understand but in terms of more secure which do you suggest